# Eclipse - maven - what goal should I execute to actually deploy to Wildfly from maven (achieve the same result as the "run on server" eclipse command)

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, wildfly, wildfly-8

New to maven - I have an eclipse project that I can *Right click > Run as... > Run on server* and it runs successfully on my local Wildfly installation. Is there a way to *RClick> Run as...* and choose an appropriate maven goal to achieve the same effect (ie package as a war, copy to the servers dir (re)staring the server) ? Do I need to use a "wildfly maven plugin" ?

Similar question for tomcat: [maven deploy goal failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241899/maven-deploy-goal-failing/2241990#2241990)

I am on eclipse Luna Java EE pack, maven 3.1 (the one that comes with eclipse) and using Wildfly 8.1.0.Final

Related:

- [One click build and deploy using Eclipse/Maven/JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298380/one-click-build-and-deploy-using-eclipse-maven-jboss-as-7)

EDIT: I am now on Wildfly - so I edited accordingly

The closest I got was:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <jbossHome>C:/_/wildfly-8.1.0.Final</jbossHome>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but I would like to avoid hardcoding the path there - how should I proceed ?

Comment: Let me know if this could help: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html this for an overview of the plugin: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy: this direction I guess - but I need to be able to run it from eclipse (via a maven launch configuration)

Comment: Maybe there is something that I do not understand... but cannot you run directly from Eclipse this goal: mvn jboss-as:deploy?

Comment: I am new to maven - I have not set up any jboss plugin - in eclipse all I have to do is set up a Jboss _runtime environment_ - then hit "Run on Server" - no clue how this translates to maven launch configurations

Comment: Ok...now i understand...Take a look at this discussion: https://community.jboss.org/thread/155668?tstart=0 i see that everyone use a different configuration...  Try also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842560/how-to-deploy-war-of-maven-project-to-jboss-server-from-eclipse

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy: thanks - had seen this but didn't bother - first is not answered + it's for eclipse Helios (ancient history) - as for your secongd link - his solution is to directly export the war in the server (duh). Had seen this too

Comment: I'm sorry...this is my way of finding soluctions... try to look for! This time it does not help :) when i'll have more time..i'll look better!

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy: thanks - this my way too (I've seen all links apart the first one already) - but then ask :D

Comment: You can "run on server" (at least now you can) with a maven war project from the Java EE perspective. When you create it, it should already have the Dynamic Web Module facet added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jboss plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.Final</version>
        </plugin>
```

Then set goal as: “jboss-as:deploy clean”

It will deploy war on JBoss server.

Comment: Thanks - will test this - meanwhile could you point me to the docs ? Is `7.5.Final` the latest version ? Is it valid for wildfly I moved to since ?

Comment: For Wildfly you need to use different plugin. but It will work as above. You can find it here https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

Comment: Hmm - this downloaded the wildfly server again :D - I am interested in running this from inside eclipse - have a maven launch configuration which will deploy to the server runtime eclipse knows about and run it. Any way ?

Comment: I tried to use WildFly plugin and it is working fine. It is downloading required jars only for first time. It deployed war on server successfully. I mentioned <webappDirectory></webappDirectory> in maven-war-plugin to generate war in server deployment.

Comment: For it me it failed - will look further - but my question was if it could use the existing wildfly install (eclipse knows about) - is where the `<webappDirectory></webappDirectory>` comes in ? Thanks for keeping me posted btw ;)

Comment: You can use System_Env variable in configuration use ${JBOSS_HOME}.
Set JBOSS_HOME to your jboss directory in env variable.

Comment: Accepting your answer - although I have more questions - namelly how to make the plugin "play" with the servers view of eclipse. Oh, well

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. For other question I am not sure what it means. :(